# Finding the value of $\sin {\frac{31 \pi}3}$

Tags: trigonometry

The task was to find out the value of $$\sin\frac{31\pi}3$$

This is a example in my book in which following steps are shown:
$$\begin{align}
\sin\frac{31\pi}3& =\sin\left(10\pi +\frac\pi3\right)\\
&=\sin\frac\pi3\\
&=\frac{\sqrt3}2
\end{align}$$

I cannot understand step 3, $=\sin\frac\pi3$

Comment: $$
\sin(n\pi+\theta)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \sin\theta & ;\quad \text{if $n$ is even},\\
\\
    -\sin\theta & ;\quad \text{if $n$ is odd}.
  \end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: I think all answers are good. But i think we can accept only one.Is there any way by which i can accept more than one ?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey you are right

Comment: Old math joke: The value of sin? Value==wages and biblically, the wages of sin is death, so the value of sin==death. Try that one on your math teacher.

Comment: @TechZen i am definetly going to try this on my maths teacher

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sine function is periodic with period $2\pi$. This means that $\sin\theta = \sin(\theta + 2\pi) \ \forall \ \theta$.  One can apply this identity five times to get rid of the $10 \pi$ term.

Comment: What? 8 upvotes? How did that happen!?

Comment: By the time you have read my last comment, the number 8 will have become obsolete.

Comment: Really...really...11 upvotes on this question

Comment: @user3001408 This is answer :)

Answer (score 8):

The sine function is periodic with period $2\pi$. A periodic function is a function that repeats its values in regular intervals or periods. A function is said to be periodic with period $P$, where $P$ being a nonzero constant if we have
$$
f(x+P) = f(x)
$$
for all values of $x$ in the domain. Therefore
$$
\sin(n\pi+\theta)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \sin\theta & ;\quad \text{if $n$ is even},\\
\\
    -\sin\theta & ;\quad \text{if $n$ is odd}.
  \end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: Unfortunately the upvotes do not increase my reputation right now. **:(** $$\\$$Thanks for the upvoters. **:)**

Comment: I think later it will be added up :)

Answer (score 6):

Multiples of $2\pi$ do not matter because $\sin$ is periodic of period $2\pi$.

Comment: The key fact is that sine is $2\pi$-periodic, and not simply periodic.

Comment: All answer are good but i am choosing this as it is shortest one

Answer (score 4):

Think of the unit circle and the definition of $\sin$: A straight line drawn from the origin with the angle between the $x$-axis of $\theta$ intersects the unit circle at $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

[image: unit circle]

Say you have a point on the unit circle at $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. If the line making the angle $\theta$ from the origin makes a full revolution (revolves around the origin by a measure of $2\pi$), then it will end up in the same position. Thus, $\sin n = \sin (2\pi + n) = \sin (n - 2\pi)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can confirm this by using the angle-sum formula:

$$\begin{align} \sin(10\pi + \pi/3) & = \sin(10\pi)\cos(\pi/3) + \cos(10 \pi)\sin(\pi/3) \\ \\ & = 0\cdot\frac 12 + 1 \cdot \sin (\pi/3) \\ \\ & = \sin(\pi/3)\\ \\ & = \sqrt 3/2\end{align}$$